# Does The Hadith In Dur Al-Manthur Mention That Isa ibn Maryam (Alayhisalam) Is Alive And He Will Return Back?

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh, tafseer

Salam All Muslim Brothers,

I have a question about a Hadith in the book "Dur Al-Manthur". Dur Al-Manthur is a book that contains narrations related to verses of the Quran. Under Surah Imran, verse 55, I have found a hadith that speaks about return of Isa ibn Maryam and in that narration it is **explicitly said that he is alive.** However, I am not sure if this narration is authentic or not. **Someone please help me find this hadith and verify the authenticity of this narration. I really, really need to find this narration and confirm its authenticity.**

Under Al-Imran, verse 55 in Dur Al-Manthur, it is stated:-

Imam Ibn Jarir and Ibn Abi Hatim has narrated a narration with another chain of narrators that Hasan Basri (Rahimahullah) has stated that Allah will cause Isa bin Maryam (Alayhisalam) to sleep and he raised Isa bin Maryam (Alayhisalam) when he was asleep. **Hasan Basri (Rahimahullah) has narrated that Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) said to the Jews that Isa bin Maryam (Alayhisalam) did not die and he will come back to you before the day of Judgement.**

The narration in question is this one: **Hasan Basri (Rahimahullah) has narrated that Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) said to the Jews that Isa bin Maryam (Alayhisalam) did not die and he will come back to you before the day of Judgement.**

NOTE: I am not an Arabic speaker. I have taken the part of Dur Al-Manthur (Urdu Version) where it is stated in Urdu that such a narration exists. Please see the picture below at the end of this question.

**Please can someone help me find this complete narration and verify its authenticity?**

Thanks.[image: This Is The Excerpt I Took From Dur Al-Manthur (Urdu Translation)]

Comment: https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/231236/

Comment: Note however that the hadith is correct in its text, the creed of Jesus being alive and returning is supported by several authentic ahadith.

Comment: @UmH- I cannot understand Arabic. Is there any English version of that site you mentioned?

Comment: Have you checked other available Tafsirs ad-Dur al-Manthur is a tafsir bil ma'athur it actually refers to ibn Jarir at-Tabari and ibn Abi Hatim which are both authors of Tafsirs of this kind and among the sources of ibn Kathir too.

Comment: No, I dont think so. It is mursal, since Hasan al-Basri narrates it directly from the Prophet ﷺ. Regarding its source, Suyuti cites it from [Ibn Jarir Tabari](https://al-maktaba.org/book/43/3354#p7) and [Ibn Abi Hatim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8658/1101#p3).

Comment: @Medi1Saif- No. I have not checked other Tafseers that are related to this issue. Other Tafsirs just mention the view of mainstream Muslims that Jesus (Alayhisalam) was raised. I do not rely upon Tafsir Jalalayn because I consider it unreliable.